# Upgrading Spring and Hibernate libraries

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, db2

We are upgrading the libraries in our application. These are all the old maven dependencies

```
<maven-war-plugin.version>2.3</maven-war-plugin.version>
<maven-release-plugin.version>2.1</maven-release-plugin.version>
<maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
<maven-soapui-plugin.version>4.0.0</maven-soapui-plugin.version>
<maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.9</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
<maven-jetty-plugin.version>6.1.25</maven-jetty-plugin.version>
<build-helper-maven-plugin.version>1.7</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>        

<!-- ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo -->
<!-- Dependency Versions -->
<!-- ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo -->

<cxf.version>2.7.12</cxf.version>
<spring.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
<slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
<hibernate.version>3.5.0-Final</hibernate.version>
<db2.version>4.19.49</db2.version>
<dozer.version>3.3.1</dozer.version>
<quartz.version>1.8.6</quartz.version>
```

These are current maven dependencies,

```
<maven-war-plugin.version>2.3</maven-war-plugin.version>
<maven-release-plugin.version>2.1</maven-release-plugin.version>
<maven-compiler-plugin.version>2.3.2</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
<maven-soapui-plugin.version>4.0.0</maven-soapui-plugin.version>
<maven-failsafe-plugin.version>2.9</maven-failsafe-plugin.version>
<maven-jetty-plugin.version>6.1.25</maven-jetty-plugin.version>
<build-helper-maven-plugin.version>1.7</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>

<!-- ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo -->
<!-- Dependency Versions -->
<!-- ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo -->

<cxf.version>3.1.11</cxf.version>
<spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
<slf4j.version>1.7.12</slf4j.version>
<hibernate.version>4.3.10.Final</hibernate.version>
<db2.version>4.19.49</db2.version>
<dozer.version>5.4.0</dozer.version>
<quartz.version>2.2.3</quartz.version>
```

We have been using `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateInterceptor` and now this has changed to `OpenSessionInterceptor` since `HibernateInterceptor` is not available in hibernate 4.

```
<!-- DAO Spring Beans wrapped with dynamic proxies -->
<bean id="evnDao" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="proxyInterfaces">
        <value>com.abc.dao.IAbcDao</value>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
        <list>
            <value>hibernateInterceptor</value>
            <value>abcDaoTarget</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateInterceptor" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInterceptor">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFacorty" />
</bean>
```

And we have fixed all the compilation error as part of the upgrade. Now the application is getting started but it is not able to communicate to the DB for properly. We are getting the below exception when we are searching,

```
2017-08-20 11:41:25,266 ERROR [https-openssl-nio-8743-exec-10::CHY4001] spi.SqlExceptionHelper - [jcc][10143][10845][4.19.49] Invalid parameter 1: Parameter is not set nor registered. ERRORCODE=-4461, SQLSTATE=42815
2017-08-20 11:41:25,282 ERROR [https-openssl-nio-8743-exec-10::CHY4001] cxf.abcCxfDispatcher - abcBaseException Rootcause: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:146)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:308)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(HibernateTemplate.java:1011)
    at abc.dao.AbcDao.findBySearchCriteria(AbcDao.java:1452)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.support.OpenSessionInterceptor.invoke(OpenSessionInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.findBySearchCriteria(Unknown Source)
    at abc.business.ProofOfInsuranceService.searchProofOfInsurance(ProofOfInsuranceService.java:1737)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy86.searchProofOfInsurance(Unknown Source)
    at com.abc.abc.cxf.abcCxfDispatcher.searchProofOfInsurance(abcCxfDispatcher.java:3024)
    at com.abc.abc.cxf.abcabc30Impl.searchProofOfInsurance(abcabc30Impl.java:120)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.performInvocation(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:262)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:218)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

while executing the below block of code,

```
HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = getHibernateTemplate();
idResults = (List<String>) hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(abcCriteria, 0,
CommonConstants.FOURHUNDRED);
```

Below the are hibernate debug log,

```
2017-08-20 17:15:53,493 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@68bb9e6
2017-08-20 17:15:53,508 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@68bb9e6
2017-08-20 17:15:53,508 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Boolean -> org.hibernate.type.BooleanType@68bb9e6
2017-08-20 17:15:53,508 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration numeric_boolean -> org.hibernate.type.NumericBooleanType@6e2d3dad
2017-08-20 17:15:53,524 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration true_false -> org.hibernate.type.TrueFalseType@67c23a1d
2017-08-20 17:15:53,524 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration yes_no -> org.hibernate.type.YesNoType@e1e6115
2017-08-20 17:15:53,524 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration byte -> org.hibernate.type.ByteType@17515f28
2017-08-20 17:15:53,524 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration byte -> org.hibernate.type.ByteType@17515f28
2017-08-20 17:15:53,524 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Byte -> org.hibernate.type.ByteType@17515f28
2017-08-20 17:15:53,524 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration character -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@48397fa0
2017-08-20 17:15:53,524 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration char -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@48397fa0
2017-08-20 17:15:53,524 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Character -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterType@48397fa0
2017-08-20 17:15:53,539 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration short -> org.hibernate.type.ShortType@8320069
2017-08-20 17:15:53,539 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration short -> org.hibernate.type.ShortType@8320069
2017-08-20 17:15:53,539 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Short -> org.hibernate.type.ShortType@8320069
2017-08-20 17:15:53,539 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration integer -> org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@3a02e22a
2017-08-20 17:15:53,555 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration int -> org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@3a02e22a
2017-08-20 17:15:53,555 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Integer -> org.hibernate.type.IntegerType@3a02e22a
2017-08-20 17:15:53,555 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration long -> org.hibernate.type.LongType@5f2b9c79
2017-08-20 17:15:53,555 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration long -> org.hibernate.type.LongType@5f2b9c79
2017-08-20 17:15:53,555 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Long -> org.hibernate.type.LongType@5f2b9c79
2017-08-20 17:15:53,571 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration float -> org.hibernate.type.FloatType@1a9c6f78
2017-08-20 17:15:53,571 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration float -> org.hibernate.type.FloatType@1a9c6f78
2017-08-20 17:15:53,571 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Float -> org.hibernate.type.FloatType@1a9c6f78
2017-08-20 17:15:53,571 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration double -> org.hibernate.type.DoubleType@1000af50
2017-08-20 17:15:53,571 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration double -> org.hibernate.type.DoubleType@1000af50
2017-08-20 17:15:53,571 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Double -> org.hibernate.type.DoubleType@1000af50
2017-08-20 17:15:53,586 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration big_decimal -> org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType@59e96489
2017-08-20 17:15:53,586 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.math.BigDecimal -> org.hibernate.type.BigDecimalType@59e96489
2017-08-20 17:15:53,586 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration big_integer -> org.hibernate.type.BigIntegerType@922405c
2017-08-20 17:15:53,586 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.math.BigInteger -> org.hibernate.type.BigIntegerType@922405c
2017-08-20 17:15:53,586 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration string -> org.hibernate.type.StringType@1d6117fd
2017-08-20 17:15:53,586 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.String -> org.hibernate.type.StringType@1d6117fd
2017-08-20 17:15:53,602 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration nstring -> org.hibernate.type.StringNVarcharType@732302ac
2017-08-20 17:15:53,602 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration ncharacter -> org.hibernate.type.CharacterNCharType@58e6788d
2017-08-20 17:15:53,617 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration url -> org.hibernate.type.UrlType@c8ffcb9
2017-08-20 17:15:53,617 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.net.URL -> org.hibernate.type.UrlType@c8ffcb9
2017-08-20 17:15:53,617 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration date -> org.hibernate.type.DateType@493eabcc
2017-08-20 17:15:53,617 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.sql.Date -> org.hibernate.type.DateType@493eabcc
2017-08-20 17:15:53,633 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration time -> org.hibernate.type.TimeType@175fa89d
2017-08-20 17:15:53,633 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.sql.Time -> org.hibernate.type.TimeType@175fa89d
2017-08-20 17:15:53,633 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration timestamp -> org.hibernate.type.TimestampType@7fdc7bdc
2017-08-20 17:15:53,633 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.sql.Timestamp -> org.hibernate.type.TimestampType@7fdc7bdc
2017-08-20 17:15:53,633 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.util.Date -> org.hibernate.type.TimestampType@7fdc7bdc
2017-08-20 17:15:53,649 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration dbtimestamp -> org.hibernate.type.DbTimestampType@1ff7ffcf
2017-08-20 17:15:53,649 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration calendar -> org.hibernate.type.CalendarType@45ef695b
2017-08-20 17:15:53,649 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.util.Calendar -> org.hibernate.type.CalendarType@45ef695b
2017-08-20 17:15:53,649 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.util.GregorianCalendar -> org.hibernate.type.CalendarType@45ef695b
2017-08-20 17:15:53,649 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration calendar_date -> org.hibernate.type.CalendarDateType@2820352f
2017-08-20 17:15:53,649 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration locale -> org.hibernate.type.LocaleType@27d25715
2017-08-20 17:15:53,649 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.util.Locale -> org.hibernate.type.LocaleType@27d25715
2017-08-20 17:15:53,664 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration currency -> org.hibernate.type.CurrencyType@46bdc451
2017-08-20 17:15:53,664 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.util.Currency -> org.hibernate.type.CurrencyType@46bdc451
2017-08-20 17:15:53,664 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration timezone -> org.hibernate.type.TimeZoneType@6443640b
2017-08-20 17:15:53,664 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.util.TimeZone -> org.hibernate.type.TimeZoneType@6443640b
2017-08-20 17:15:53,664 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration class -> org.hibernate.type.ClassType@36b64f64
2017-08-20 17:15:53,664 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Class -> org.hibernate.type.ClassType@36b64f64
2017-08-20 17:15:53,664 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration uuid-binary -> org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@31e970c1
2017-08-20 17:15:53,664 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.util.UUID -> org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@31e970c1
2017-08-20 17:15:53,680 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration uuid-char -> org.hibernate.type.UUIDCharType@161cf2d8
2017-08-20 17:15:53,680 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration pg-uuid -> org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType@669abb3c
2017-08-20 17:15:53,680 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration binary -> org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@fe8bd23
2017-08-20 17:15:53,680 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration byte[] -> org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@fe8bd23
2017-08-20 17:15:53,680 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration [B -> org.hibernate.type.BinaryType@fe8bd23
2017-08-20 17:15:53,680 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration wrapper-binary -> org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@6e53e95c
2017-08-20 17:15:53,680 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration Byte[] -> org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@6e53e95c
2017-08-20 17:15:53,680 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration [Ljava.lang.Byte; -> org.hibernate.type.WrapperBinaryType@6e53e95c
2017-08-20 17:15:53,695 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration image -> org.hibernate.type.ImageType@7a3a235d
2017-08-20 17:15:53,695 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration characters -> org.hibernate.type.CharArrayType@538fc179
2017-08-20 17:15:53,742 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration java.lang.Object -> org.hibernate.type.ObjectType@23922fd6
2017-08-20 17:15:53,758 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_date -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@1ecbacb2
2017-08-20 17:15:53,758 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_time -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@2c15dc22
2017-08-20 17:15:53,758 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_timestamp -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@26d7b421
2017-08-20 17:15:53,758 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_dbtimestamp -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@55303671
2017-08-20 17:15:53,758 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_calendar -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@16ddbe59
2017-08-20 17:15:53,758 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_calendar_date -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@14ab946c
2017-08-20 17:15:53,758 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_binary -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@fc65c64
2017-08-20 17:15:53,758 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1::] type.BasicTypeRegistry - Adding type registration imm_serializable -> org.hibernate.type.AdaptedImmutableType@5b116053
2017-08-20 17:16:00,201 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1::] hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Using DataSource [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource[ identityToken -> 2tivw19q255db1l5z52w|77a05dcf, dataSourceName -> 2tivw19q255db1l5z52w|77a05dcf ]] of Hibernate SessionFactory for HibernateTransactionManager
2017-08-20 17:18:32,599 DEBUG [https-openssl-nio-8743-exec-10::CHY4001] support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.abc.ProofOfInsuranceService.searchProofOfInsurance]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly
2017-08-20 17:18:32,755 DEBUG [https-openssl-nio-8743-exec-10::CHY4001] hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Opened new Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@ea6bb5 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3356ebd2 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b6a055c orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4cd9a363 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1f3dce8e collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1bb1aec0 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@40aa080f collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@416979c2 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] for Hibernate transaction
2017-08-20 17:18:32,755 DEBUG [https-openssl-nio-8743-exec-10::CHY4001] hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@ea6bb5 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3356ebd2 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b6a055c orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4cd9a363 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1f3dce8e collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1bb1aec0 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@40aa080f collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@416979c2 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
2017-08-20 17:18:32,817 DEBUG [https-openssl-nio-8743-exec-10::CHY4001] hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@5d7e5163 [wrapping: com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.b@1b2be0c1]]
2017-08-20 17:18:33,192 DEBUG [https-openssl-nio-8743-exec-10::CHY4001] spi.SqlStatementLogger - 
    select
        this_.ID as y0_ 
    from
        EVN.EVN this_ 
    where
        this_.SOURCEAPPLICATION=? 
        and this_.SOURCEAPPLICATIONID=? 
    group by
        this_.ID fetch first 400 rows only
2017-08-20 17:18:33,254 DEBUG [https-openssl-nio-8743-exec-10::CHY4001] support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
2017-08-20 17:18:33,254 DEBUG [https-openssl-nio-8743-exec-10::CHY4001] hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@ea6bb5 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3356ebd2 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b6a055c orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4cd9a363 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1f3dce8e collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1bb1aec0 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@40aa080f collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@416979c2 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])]
2017-08-20 17:18:33,254 DEBUG [https-openssl-nio-8743-exec-10::CHY4001] hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager - Closing Hibernate Session [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@ea6bb5 updates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@3356ebd2 deletions=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@b6a055c orphanRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@4cd9a363 collectionCreations=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1f3dce8e collectionRemovals=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@1bb1aec0 collectionUpdates=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@40aa080f collectionQueuedOps=org.hibernate.engine.spi.ExecutableList@416979c2 unresolvedInsertDependencies=UnresolvedEntityInsertActions[]])] after transaction
```

Can anyone please help on this issue.

Comment: Is this error comes from when you call a stored procedure? or it happens even if you try to execute a sql query?  Have you tried enabling the show_sql to true? in order to debug the sql sentences.

Comment: We are getting the exception for all sql query. We tried show_sql to true option,but the sql seems to be fine.I have updated the sql logs in my question @DanielC.

Comment: Hello @alexbt. Did you find a solution?